# How to set encodeUriComponent in part of URI in Power Automate

Tags: power-automate

I am making an HTTP request in Power automate like the below image

[image]

Where in URI part, I am using **id** but I needed it encoded. I tried with expression **encodeUriComponent** but then it is not allowing me to select **id** as an argument inside it. How can I achieve that in power automate?
This is all flow image.
[image]

and from response of posts I receive this JSON

```
{
"paging": {
    "start": 0,
    "count": 10,
    "links": [],
    "total": 5
},
"elements": [
    {
        "isReshareDisabledByAuthor": false,
        "createdAt": 1704885697456,
        "lifecycleState": "PUBLISHED",
        "lastModifiedAt": 1704887404834,
        "visibility": "PUBLIC",
        "publishedAt": 1704885697456,
        "author": "urn:li:organization:101410019",
        "id": "urn:li:share:7150808899816669184",
        "distribution": {
            "feedDistribution": "MAIN_FEED",
            "thirdPartyDistributionChannels": []
        },
        "content": {
            "media": {
                "altText": "",
                "id": "urn:li:image:D5622AQEcyXncoACqYw"
            }
        },
        "commentary": "single Image",
        "lifecycleStateInfo": {
            "isEditedByAuthor": false
        }
    },
    {
        "isReshareDisabledByAuthor": false,
        "lifecycleState": "PUBLISHED",
        "createdAt": 1704885749848,
        "lastModifiedAt": 1704885749848,
        "visibility": "PUBLIC",
        "publishedAt": 1704885749848,
        "author": "urn:li:organization:101410019",
        "id": "urn:li:share:7150809119690510336",
        "distribution": {
            "feedDistribution": "MAIN_FEED",
            "thirdPartyDistributionChannels": []
        },
        "commentary": "No Image",
        "lifecycleStateInfo": {
            "isEditedByAuthor": false
        }
    },
    {
        "isReshareDisabledByAuthor": false,
        "createdAt": 1704885735784,
        "lifecycleState": "PUBLISHED",
        "lastModifiedAt": 1704885735832,
        "visibility": "PUBLIC",
        "publishedAt": 1704885735784,
        "author": "urn:li:organization:101410019",
        "id": "urn:li:ugcPost:7150809060592771072",
        "distribution": {
            "feedDistribution": "MAIN_FEED",
            "thirdPartyDistributionChannels": []
        },
        "content": {
            "multiImage": {
                "images": [
                    {
                        "altText": "",
                        "id": "urn:li:image:D5622AQHI1OTfTOM0ew"
                    },
                    {
                        "altText": "",
                        "id": "urn:li:image:D5622AQFrLq7yW1xpIw"
                    },
                    {
                        "altText": "",
                        "id": "urn:li:image:D5622AQGQMzLv9E200A"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "commentary": "Multiple Images",
        "lifecycleStateInfo": {
            "isEditedByAuthor": false
        }
    }
]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the Expression editor (1), then in the parenthesis(2), switch to Dynamic content (3) and select.

[image]

`uriComponent()` is prefered over `encodeUriComponent()`

Maybe try this as your full expression:

```
uriComponent(items('Apply to each')?['content/media/id'])
```

And for your `If no`, you will need to add another `Apply to each` action, and set it with `items('Apply to each')?['content/multiImage/images']`.
Then in there, to get the id, it would be:

```
uriComponent(items('new apply to each name')?['id'])
```

Comment: in uriComponent also I am not able to select id

Comment: I have updated the question for better understanding.